# Maven version custom upgrading

Tags: maven, plugins, version, maven-release-plugin

I am working on a maven project and it is currently versioned at 0.x, I need to be able to bump the version to X.0 using the maven release plugin. Is this possible?

I came across the maven versions plugin http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/usage.html but wasnt sure if this could be used to achive what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish your needs.

Either you use the [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) which means in other words to create a relealse including creation of tag in your version control which might not be what you like to do.

Or go via the versions-maven-plugin by which it can be simply done by using:

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Comment: thanks! Do I need this dependency in my pom? (for the versions plugin)

Comment: I would suggest to do a `pluginManagement` section to pin the version of all plugin not only versions-maven-plugin cause it's best practice to pin all plugins version to make your build reliable and reproducible.

Comment: Got it, so to make it clear, I enforce the version to 1.0-SNAPSHOT and then use the release plugin as usual right?